# Python замена строки по маске

Tags: python, mask

Мне необходимо заменить стоку:

```
link("http:)//[config.server]"
```

на

```
link("http://[config.server]")
```

при этом вместо [config.server] может стоять всё что угодно. Т.е нужно как-то использовать маску.

Пытался использовать re.sub, но не нашёл символа, который мог заменить полноценную строку

Comment: Вам только `)` нужно убрать? `replace` не подойдет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я вижу три варианта:

1. Удалить из строки одиннадцатый символ (это индекс закрывающейся скобки), приписать к строке закрывающую скобку.

   ```
   def replace1(s):
       n = len('link("http:')
       return s[:n] + s[n + 1:] + ')'
   ```
2. Заменить `link("http:)` на `link("http:`, затем приписать к строке закрывающую скобку.

   ```
   def replace2(s):
       return s.replace('link("http:)', 'link("http:') + ')'
   ```
3. Использовать регулярные выражения. «символа, который мог заменить полноценную строку» в них нет, но желаемый результат даст последовательность символов `.*`. Здесь `.` означает *любой символ*, а `*` означает *повторить предыдущий символ любое число раз*.

   ```
   def replace3(s):
       return re.sub(r'^link\("http:\)(.*)', r'link("http:\1)', s)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

4. доп. вариант через анализ сравнение символов (имеет место быть, если внутри квадратных скобок не будет символа ")"):

   ```
   tt = '''link("http:)//[config.server]"'''  
   print "".join(x for x in tt if x!=")") + ")"
   ```

Но в хорошей программе не должно быть манипуляций подобно той, в которой нуждается автор. Попробуйте пересмотреть код при заборе этой строки - при её формировании и пр.

Comment: В `join()` можно не передавать список, просто уберите скобки.

Comment: обновил, генератор на вход...

Comment: Я не знаю, но разве обычный `tt.replace(')', '')` не будет быстрее работать?

Comment: К тому же можно написать `tt.replace(')', '', count=1)`, что заменит только первую открывающуюся скобку.

Comment: За `count = 1` спасибо, нужно глянуть документацию на простые текстовые методы, что-то еще можно для себя открыть...